# How to combine beamer Frame Attributes?

Tags: pandoc

I am working on a presentation using Beamer in RMarkdown and I would like to have plain and allowframebreaks at the same time.

I know, that I can use `{.allowframebreaks}` and `{.plain}` separately, but how can I combine them so that both are applied to the same frame? All my tries resulted on them being used as text.

Thanks,

Rainer

Comment: No - but it works. I tried comma and  semicolon. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc supports attributes, among other things [on headers](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#header-identifiers), e.g. for beamer:

```
# foo {.allowframebreaks .plain}
```

The general syntax is:

```
# bar {#identifier .class .class key=value key=value}
```

Comment: How does the second, more general formulation, relate to beamer?

Comment: @Rainer not at all, that's just the general syntax... (clarified my answer)

Comment: Thanks - makes sense.